# Support for ActiveSync

Tags: windows-ce, activesync

I have a winCE device. I need to know whether the device has support for activesync. How can I check whether the device has support for ActiveSync?

Answer (score 1):

Plug it in to a PC and see if the PC makes a connection?

Seriously, how, exactly, do you want to "check"? Programatically? Manually looking at the device?  Some other way?

If you built the OS, it's in the catalog of the OS build.

If you didn't, then there's a file in the \Windows folder called "ceconfig.h" that outlines all of the SYSGENS used to build your OS, if it contains something like `SYSGEN_AS_BASE` or `SYSGEN_AS_MAIL` then at least some of the ActiveSync synchronization stuff was selected to be in the OS (though there are always ways to subvert the sysgen process, so it could still be missing, likewise it could also be there without the sysgen being defined).  It would also bepresent in ce.bib, so if your OEM shipped you an NK.BIN and ce.bib, you could check that without even booting the device.

At runtime from an on-device app, you could look at the file system. The ActiveSync device-side piece is in `repllog.exe`, so it's presence in the `\Windows` folder would also be a strong indicator of inclusion in the OS.